# Jquery element lost draggable effect after transferring divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im new with Jquery UI Draggable. heres my problem, I have 2 Divs which items may be transfered between two divs. Why does the draggable effect lost when a div transferred to other div then returned? I cannot use helper clone. element must be draggable at all time.

Here is to replicate the issue on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w7vjuuqx/7/:

1. drag and drop the blue box from red box to green box.
2. drag and drop the blue box from green box to red box.
3. repeat step 1. here the drag effect lost.

JS:

```
$('.item').draggable();

$( '#placeholder' ).droppable({
    accept: '.item',
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
      var droppable = $(this);
      var draggable = ui.draggable;
      $(draggable).attr('class', 'new_item_inside');
      draggable.appendTo(droppable);
      draggable.css({position: 'absolute', top: '0px', left: '0px'});
      alert('hello');
    }
});

$( '#item_holder' ).droppable({
  accept: '.new_item_inside',
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    var droppable = $(this);
    var draggable = ui.draggable;
    // var html = $(ui.draggable).clone(true);
     ui.draggable.draggable('enable');
    $(draggable).attr('class', 'item');
    draggable.appendTo('#item_holder');
    draggable.css({position: 'static', float: 'left'});

  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="item_holder" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red">
   <div class="item" style="width:20px;height:20px;background-color:blue">
       test
   </div>
</div>
<div id="placeholder" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:green;border-style: solid;display: inline-block;position:relative">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add the below code on your .item draggable, you should see visually the dragging action.  However, you'll notice, the original now stays in place, and the clone is the draggable.  But I think the user will know what to do with this.  It won't be confusing.

```
$('.item').draggable({
 revert: "invalid",
 helper: "clone",
 cursor : "move",
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/w7vjuuqx/10/)

Comment: Thanks KyleK. I forgot to mention that I cant use helper clone because the item on green div should be able to be draggable inside it and able to change location. any idea how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

This use case is easily solvable with the use of the *sortable* api. You connect two elements with `connectWith` then use the different events (such as receive -the rest of them are here http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) to manipulate further:

JS:

```
$('.itemContainer').sortable({
    connectWith: $('.itemContainer'),
  receive: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.item[0].innerHTML);
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="leftHolder" class="itemContainer">
  <li class="draggableItem">1</li>
  <li class="draggableItem">2</li>
  <li class="draggableItem">3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="rightHolder" class="itemContainer">
</ul>
```

FIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/gy2y5dj2/

Comment: how would I make the draggable items with absolute position? I am making a map and items should have absolute position. Thank you